# Programmatically Add New Choice to Choice Column in SharePoint List

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm working with a client and trying to make it so that when a button is pressed to open new Fiscal Year (FY) forms, it also adds that FY value as a choice option in a Document Library column.  I also am trying to set the default to that new value.

I'm getting the error below.
[image: Error Message]

Here's my current code.  Is it simply a configuration issue?  Or am I doing something n00by with my code?

```
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint
...
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
...
Protected Sub SaveNew_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveNew.Click

 ...

                'Added 6/12/2019 - Testing new FY options in Document Upload Form
                Using site As New SPSite("http://sptest/spsite/default.aspx")
                    Using web As SPWeb = site.OpenWeb()
                        Dim leadLst As SPList = web.Lists("Document Library")
                        Dim col As SPFieldChoice = CType(leadLst.Fields("Fiscal Year"), SPFieldChoice)
                        col.Choices.Add(FY.Text)
                        col.DefaultValue = FY.Text
                        col.update()
                        leadLst.update()
                    End Using
                End Using
                'End Added 6/12/2019

 ...

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creting an object of SPSite, you need to pass the URL of Site Collection only not with .aspx page
Convert your SPSite object creation line from

```
 Using site As New SPSite("http://sptest/spsite/default.aspx")
```

to

```
Using site As New SPSite("http://sptest/spsite/")
```

if spsite is your subsite and above code do not work then convert that line to

Using site As New SPSite("http://sptest/")

And then get SPWeb object for the spsite subsite

Let me know if this helps or not?